# Is there a way to rename keyword when robotframework init?

Tags: robotframework

I have one keyword file for two product to use.Then these product have their own call keyword rule.
For example:

*** Keywords ***

Keyword 1

Then i want to call *Keyword 1* in product A is *Product A Keyword 1* ,in product B is *Product B Keyword 1*

It resloved in python keyword by metaclass to add prefix when **new** the python class.
Is there any way to reslove it in robotframework keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix the keyword with it's resource file name then you can call keyword with same name but different implementation from different resource files like this:

**main.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    MyResource1.resource
Resource    MyResource2.resource

*** Tasks ***
testink
  MyResource1.MyKeyword
  MyResource2.MyKeyword
```

**MyResource1.resource**

```
*** Keywords ***
MyKeyword
  Log To Console    "This Is MyKeyword from MyResource1"
```

**MyResource2.resource**

```
*** Keywords ***
MyKeyword
  Log To Console    "MyKeyword from MyResource2 saying hi!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I correctly understood your question but I feel like you are looking for how to use embedded keywords. Here is an example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    This is product_A keyword
    This is product_B keyword

*** Keywords ***
This is ${product} keyword
    Log To Console    ${product}
```